# Connecting to a MSAccess database with ASP/HTML

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I'm trying to connect to a database this way:
(via http://localhost/test1.asp)


Form to database

<%
Set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open server.mappath("database.mdb")
%>

And it's not working!
I get this message:

An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.

If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE, uncheck the "Show friendly HTTP error messages" under "Internet Options" -> "Advanced" and you should see a more descriptive error message that may help.

Comment: HI there! Thanks for your help. After showing friendly.. I get the following message: Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005'

Operation must use an updateable query.

Comment: This would imply that the problem is with whatever query you are running, not in the connection.

Comment: @eve It is possible that you have not set the permissions for iusr, you might also like to post the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question I suspect you're relatively new to programming?

The link you pasted to localhost nly works on your computer (localhost means just that).

Read here about opening a connection to Access: http://www.webwiz.co.uk/kb/asp_tutorials/connecting_to_a_database.asp

Also, you might want to start with ASP.Net instead of the old asp. Just click the shiny button and everything will be installed on your computer: http://www.asp.net/downloads

Good luck,

GJ